# Modify "Move to Trash" shortcut in Apple Numeric keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, trash

I recently purchased Apple wired USB keyboard with Numeric Keypad for my Mac Mini (best decision I ever made, keyboard is freaking awesome with two USB ports on its sides!).

I noticed that there is a delete key under F13 key. My wish is to modify the "Move to Trash" command's shortcut inside the File menu of Finder and map to this key, just like how it is done in Windows. There was a problem with Home and End keys, but I searched and got the fix (by creating and editing DefaultKeyBindings.dict) file. If something needs to be added to this file, can someone please let me know? or if there is any other method, kindly share the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the NSUserKeyEquivalents dictionary in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Move to Trash' '\U007F'
killall Finder
```

It also makes ⌦ move items to trash in rename mode, and it makes ⌘⌫ do nothing.

Forward delete is \U007F and delete is \b or \U0008, even though in DefaultKeyBinding.dict delete is \U007F and forward delete is \UF728. The shortcut string format is described in the [Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) article.

Comment: should it not be \UF728? The idea is to use forward delete key to move a file to the trash, which stands for the unicode key \UF728.